# How do I plot a filled cylinder in 3D?

Tags: graphics3d, image-processing

All,

I'm trying to plot a filled cylinder in 3D using `Graphics3D` and then take 2D slices of said cylinder.  I know that Cylinder is officially 'filled', but the 2D slices that I take are hollow.  Here's my code:

```
image = Cylinder[{{-5, -5, -5}, {5, 5, 5}}];

graphic2 = 
 Graphics3D[{GrayLevel[0], EdgeForm[Thick], image}, Boxed -> False, 
  Axes -> True]

data = Flatten[
  Table[Show[graphic2, ViewPoint -> {0, 0, -Infinity}, 
    PlotRange -> {{-5.5, 5.5}, {-5.5, 5.5}, {z, z + 0.1}}, 
    Ticks -> False], {z, -5.5, 5.5, 0.1}], 2]
```

`image` is the cylinder, `graphic2` is the graphic itself, and `data` is a table of 2D slices of said cylinder.  However, these slices are hollow; I need them to be filled.  Any recommendations?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise. 2) Read the [faq](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour)! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by [clicking the checkmark sign](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/)!

Comment: You can format inline code and code blocks by selecting it and clicking the `{}` button above the edit window.  The edit window  help button `?` is also useful for learning how to format your questions and answers.

Comment: Oh, I didn't know he did any formatting.  My bad, I'm new to this.  I tried to do what he said with the {} button, and I guess I undid what he did.

Comment: For this particular example I would do the math and use `Disk` to draw an ellipse as a 2d graphic.  You will get a sharper quality figure..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a set-up similar to [Taiki](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/5906/taiki), but taking literally the OP's request for 2D slices instead of the thin 3D slices in the OP's code:

```
SeedRandom[1];
xrange = {-5, 5};
yrange = {-5, 5};
zrange = {-5, 5};
cylinders = Table[Cylinder[
    Table[RandomReal /@ {xrange, yrange, zrange}, {2}]], {10}];

plots = Block[{reg},
    reg = Compile @@ {{x, y, z}, 
       Rest@RegionMember[RegionUnion @@ cylinders, {x, y, z}]};
    Table[
     RegionPlot[
      reg[x, y, z],
      {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}
      ],
     {z, -5.5, 5.5, 0.1}]
    ];
```

[image]

It takes about five seconds on my machine.  Compiling made it ten times as fast.

Comment: Much faster than my approach!

Comment: @Taiki One would expect 2D to be faster than 3D, even much faster, but thanks!

Comment: Something esoteric seems to be going on here. Why does in your function `Compile@@{...}` work but `Compile[...]` doesn't? And what does `Last` do?

Comment: @Taiki `Compile` is `HoldAll`, but I need the body `Last@RegionMember...` to evaluate to an algebraic inequality to get a compilable expression.  The `RegionMember` expression starts with `Element[(x | y | z), Reals] && (<inequalities>)`, which is irrelevant and not compilable.  `Last` returns only the inequalities.  `Rest` might be safer (e.g. if applied to `RegionIntersection`) -- actually I'll change the code because it is a better model.

Comment: Thank you for your help!!!  This is great!  I didn't actually realize that I was getting thin 3D slices rather than 2D slices.

Comment: This might be the wrong place to ask this, but how to ya'll get so good at Mathematica coding?  Webinars?  Seminars?  Days on end of trial and error?

Comment: @Hogy88 25 years ago, I read the manual. About fifteen years ago I got a grant to write QuickTime animations illustrating multivariable calculus concepts and used Mathematica; learned by reading the manual. Translated the animations to `Manipulate` when V6 came out, by reading the manual. Wrote for the Demonstrations project. Found this site a couple of years ago; learned a lot here that I didn't get from reading the manual. But practice, solving problems that arise, and reading the manual were the main things. Being a mathematics professor with a smidgen of CS has helped me be a good learner.

Answer (score 3):

Let me present a geometric approach.

```
xrange = {-5, 5};
yrange = {-4, 4};
zrange = {-3, 3};
rrange = {1/2, 1};
xrangeext = {-#, #} &@ Max[rrange] + xrange;
yrangeext = {-#, #} &@ Max[rrange] + yrange;
zrangeext = {-#, #} &@ Max[rrange] + zrange;
cylinders = Table[
  Cylinder[Table[RandomReal /@ {xrange, yrange, zrange}, {2}], RandomReal[rrange]],
  {10}
];
Graphics3D[{EdgeForm[], Red, cylinders}]
```

[image: random cylinders]

Essentially the approach involves discretising the cylinders only within the prescribed bounds. This results in crisp cuts, but computationally expensive though.

```
zslice[obj_, zs_] := If[
  AnyTrue[
    RandomReal[zs, 10],
    Length@FindInstance[RegionMember[obj, {xval, yval, #}], {xval, yval}] != 0 &
  ],
  If[!MatchQ[#, _DiscretizeRegion], MeshPrimitives[#, 2]] &[
    DiscretizeRegion[obj, {xrangeext, yrangeext, zs}
]]];
```

For demonstration let me use 80 not-so-thin continuous slices of thickness 1/10 from -4 to 4.

```
slicings = Partition[Range[Sequence @@ zrangeext, 1/10], 2, 1];
slices = Function[{min, max}, zslice[#, {min, max}] & /@ cylinders] @@@ slicings;
Graphics3D[
  {
    EdgeForm[],
    Red,
    #
  },
  Boxed -> False,
  PlotRange -> {xrangeext, yrangeext, zrangeext},
  ViewPoint -> {0, 0, -Infinity}
] & /@ slices
```

[image: z-slicings of cylinders]

Multi-coloured chalks:

```
slicings = Partition[Range[Sequence @@ zrangeext, 1], 2, 1];
Graphics3D[
  {
    EdgeForm[],
    Function[
      {min, max},
      {RandomColor[], zslice[#, {min, max}] & /@ cylinders}
    ] @@@ slicings
  },
  Boxed -> False,
  PlotRange -> {xrangeext, yrangeext, zrangeext}
]
```

[image: chalks]

Comment: Excellent, thanks for the help!  This and the other answers have covered my question with great detail!

Answer (score 1):

```
ℛ = 
  ImplicitRegion[x^2 + y^2 <= 1 && Abs[z] < 5, {x, y, z}];

RegionPlot3D[ℛ, PlotPoints -> 100,
  PlotRange -> {{-2, 2}, {-2, 2}, {-6, 6}}] // Quiet
```

[image]

```
slice =RegionIntersection[ℛ, 
 ImplicitRegion[x^2 + y^2 < 2 && Abs[z - .5] < .01, {x, y, z}]];

RegionPlot3D[slice, PlotPoints -> 100,
  PlotRange -> {{-2, 2}, {-2, 2}, {-6, 6}}] // Quiet
```

[image]

Comment: This works if I only needed one slice, but I'm not sure if this will work in my final code.  I will be placing up to 400 small cylinders at random and with random orientations in a single Graphics3D, and I need to take 2D slices of this conglomerate.

Comment: No problem.  Just define the slices wherever you want, and at any orientation.  You should pose your full question as it is unfair to respondents to answer the posed question only to be told that it wasn't "really" what you need.

Comment: @David G. Stork In my case (Win7, Mma 10.1) the last statement returned an empty plot.